# Transfer Data between MySQL and MongoDB Databases

Tags: mysql, mongodb, migration

My latest IT project has me working with MongoDB for the first time.  While I have a bit (very little) experience with NoSQL, I have always mostly worked with MySQL using Workbench.

I need to migrate the data from a MySQL database into MongoDB as my employer is switching over from the former to the latter.

Can someone suggest what might be the easiest way to do that?

Thanks a bundle!

Answer (score 1):

This will probably get closed, but last time I was working with MongoDB heavily (1-2 years ago) nothing beat [RoboMongo](https://robomongo.org/). It was free before and is open sourced now as well, which is pretty neat.

Comment: Now the "RoboMongo" officially name becomes "Robo 3T".

Comment: Robomongo / Robo3T has always been open source. Unfortunately development is sporadic and as of July 2018 the latest Robo3T release is based on the MongoDB 3.4 shell. There have been two major release series since 3.4 (MongoDB 3.6 and 4.0) so I would look for a more actively maintained tool for full compatibility.